# Retrieve rows based on column of type "time" in cassandra db

Tags: cassandra

How to retrieve rows based on column of type "time" in `cassandra` db.

We tried with query

```
select * 
from payment_transactions_by_transactiondate
where transaction_time>='00:00:00' 
and transaction_time<='23:59:59'  
and transaction_date='2018-03-21'
allow filtering;
```

, 
but its not fetching the rows (`where transaction_time is a primary key`).

Answer (score 0):

You can not do a range query on the primary key. It's because Cassandra distributes data on different node based on a primary key. Instead What you can do, is to make the `transaction_time` clustering key. See the difference between [primary key and clustering key](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html). From the above query, it seems you need transactions in a particular date(**transaction_date**). So to do this query make ***`transaction_date`*** primary key and  ***`transaction_time`***  clustering key.

For example:

```
create table payment_transactions_by_transactiondate( 
      ....
      ....
      .... 
      primary key (transaction_date, transaction_time)
);
```